# Magento 2 : How to add image upload in ui form

Tags: magento2, image-upload, ui-form

How to add image uploader as like in the category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference Link : [Click Here](https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-upload-image-using-ui-component-in-magento-2/)

Follow this below steps to add image uploader in ui form :

> 1) Add this below code in your form's xml file :

```
<field name="review_image">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor_module/index/upload"/>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

> 2) Now, you need to create **virtualType** of Image uploader in di.xml file. Add this below code in your **di.xml** file :

```
<!-- Image Uploader -->
<virtualType name="VirtualTypeName" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">productreview/tmp/image</argument>
        <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">productreview/image</argument>
        <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Upload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">VirtualTypeName</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<!-- End Image Uploader -->
```

> 3) Now, create controller **upload.php** and add this below code :

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * Upload constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute() {
        $imageUploadId = $this->_request->getParam('param_name', 'review_image');
        try {
            $imageResult = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir($imageUploadId);

            $imageResult['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $imageResult = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($imageResult);
    }
}
```

> 4) Then, you need to add js file in **requirejs-config.js** file. Add this below code in your **requirejs-config.js** file :

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader': 'VendorName_ModuleName/js/form/element/file-uploader'
        }
    }
};
```

> 5) Then, copy js file from **/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/file-uploader.js** and add into **VendorName_ModuleName/js/form/element/file-uploader** folder.

Refresh it and check it.

Comment: where to define the image directory path?

Answer (score 2):

**computer_games_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider"
                  xsi:type="string">computer_games_form.game_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Computer Game
            Information</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save"
                    class="Vendor\ComputerGames\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Save"/>
            <button name="delete"
                    class="Vendor\ComputerGames\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Delete"/>
            <button name="back"
                    class="Vendor\ComputerGames\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Back"/>
            <button name="save_and_continue"
                    class="Vendor\ComputerGames\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\SaveAndContinueButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>computer_games_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>computer_games_form.game_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="game_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component"
                      xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="games/game/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Moazzam\ComputerGames\Model\Game\DataProvider"
                      name="game_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>game_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>game_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <settings>
            <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
            <label translate="true">Information</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="game_id" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">computer_games</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <dataScope>game_id</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="name" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">computer_games</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="type" formElement="select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">computer_games</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>number</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Type</label>
                <dataScope>type</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options
                            class="Vendor\ComputerGames\Ui\Component\Options\Types"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        <field name="trial_period" formElement="select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">computer_games</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>number</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Trial Period</label>
                <dataScope>trial_period</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options
                            class="Vendor\ComputerGames\Ui\Component\Options\TrialPeriods"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        <field name="image" formElement="imageUploader">
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <notice translate="true">Allowed file types: jpeg, gif, png.</notice>
                <label translate="true">Image</label>
                <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <imageUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <maxFileSize>2097152</maxFileSize>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="string"
                                   name="url">games/game_fileUploader/save</param>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                    </settings>
                </imageUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        <field name="release_date" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">computer_games</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Release Date</label>
                <dataScope>release_date</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
    <?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\ComputerGames\Controller\Adminhtml\Game;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException as AlreadyExistsExceptionAlias;
use Vendor\ComputerGames\Model\GameFactory;
use Vendor\ComputerGames\Model\ResourceModel\Game as GameResourceModel;

/**
 * Save the data
 *
 * Class Save
 */
class Save extends Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ImageUploader
     */
    protected ImageUploader $imageUploader;

    /**
     * @var GameFactory
     */
    protected GameFactory $gameFactory;

    /**
     * @var GameResourceModel
     */
    protected GameResourceModel $gameResourceModel;
    private Context $context;

    /**
     * @param GameResourceModel $gameResourceModel
     * @param GameFactory $gameFactory
     * @param ImageUploader $imageUploader
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        GameResourceModel $gameResourceModel,
        GameFactory $gameFactory,
        ImageUploader $imageUploader,
        Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader=$imageUploader;
        $this->gameFactory = $gameFactory;
        $this->gameResourceModel = $gameResourceModel;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * @return ResultInterface
     * @throws AlreadyExistsExceptionAlias
     */
    public function execute(): ResultInterface
    {
        $postData = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $model = $this->gameFactory->create();
        if ($postData['game_id']) {
            $this->gameResourceModel->load($model, $postData['game_id']);
        } else {
            unset($postData['game_id']);
        }
        $model->setData($postData);
        if (isset($postData['image'])) {
            try {
                $bannerImage = $postData['image'][0];
                if (strpos($bannerImage['url'], 'computer/image') !== false) {
                    if (isset($bannerImage['file']) && !empty($bannerImage['file'])) {
                        $image = (string)$postData['image'][0]['name'];
                        $imageName = $this->imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($image);
                        $model->setData('image', $imageName);
                    } else {
                        $imageName = (explode("/", $bannerImage['url']));
                        $model->setData('image', $imageName[6]);
                    }
                } else {
                    $imageName = (explode("/", $bannerImage['url']));
                    $model->setData('image', $imageName[6]);
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $imageName = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
            }
        }
        $this->gameResourceModel->save($model);
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Game Form has been saved');
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $result->setPath('games/game/index');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**dbschema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="computer_games" engine="innodb" comment="Computer games table" resource="default">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="game_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Primary" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" comment="Name" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="type" nullable="false" comment="Game type: RPG, Simulator, Shooter, RTS, MMO" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="trial_period"  nullable="false" comment="Trial period" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="image" nullable="false" comment="Game Image" />
        <column xsi:type="date" name="release_date" nullable="false" comment="Release date" />
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="game_id" />
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**\Vendor\ComputerGames\Controller\Adminhtml\Game\FileUploader\Save**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\ComputerGames\Controller\Adminhtml\Game\FileUploader;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface as ResultInterfaceAlias;

/**
 * Upload the images of games
 *
 * Class Save
 */
class Save extends Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ImageUploader
     */
    protected ImageUploader $imageUploader;

    /**
     * @param ImageUploader $imageUploader
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(ImageUploader $imageUploader, Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader=$imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Allow
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Save the games images through helper
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterfaceAlias
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('image');
            $result['cookie'] = [
               'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
               'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain()
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }

        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

**\Vendor\ComputerGames\Model\Game\DataProvider**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ComputerGames\Model\Game;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider as AbstractDataProvider;
use Vendor\ComputerGames\Model\ResourceModel\Game\Collection;
use Vendor\ComputerGames\Model\ResourceModel\Game\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * PLEASE ENTER ONE LINE SHORT DESCRIPTION OF CLASS
 *
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected array $loadedData;

    protected $storeManger;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $gameCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $gameCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $gameCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->storeManger=$storeManager;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData(): array
    {
        $baseurl =  $this->storeManger->getStore()->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        $this->loadedData = [];
        if (!empty($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $game) {
            $temp = $game->getData();
            $img = [];
            $img[0]['name'] = $temp['image'];
            $img[0]['url'] = $baseurl . 'computer/image/' . $temp['image'];
            $temp['image'] = $img;
            $this->loadedData[$game->getId()] = array_merge($game->getData(), $temp);
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/ComputerGames/view/adminhtml/ui_component/computer_games_listing.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd ">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">computer_games_listing.computer_games_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/game/edit" />
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Add New Game</label>
                <aclResource>Magento_Sales::create</aclResource>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <spinner>computer_games_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>computer_games_listing.computer_games_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="computer_games_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render" />
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Vendor_ComputerGames::grid</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="ComputerGamesGridDataProvider" name="computer_games_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>main_table.game_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks" />
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls" />
        <exportButton name="export_button" />
        <filterSearch name="fulltext" />
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <paging name="listing_paging" />
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="computer_games_columns">
        <settings>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">
                        computer_games_listing.computer_games_listing.computer_games_column
                        s.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <column name="game_id" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="type" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="Vendor\ComputerGames\Ui\Component\Options\Types" />
                <filter>select</filter>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Type</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="trial_period">
            <settings>
                <options class="Vendor\ComputerGames\Ui\Component\Options\TrialPeriods" />
                <filter>select</filter>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Trial Period</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="release_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date"
                component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Release Date</label>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="image" class="Vendor\ComputerGames\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ImageThumbnail"
                component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail" sortOrder="0" displayArea="generalarea">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">games</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Image</label>
                <hasPreview>1</hasPreview>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\ComputerGames\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\GameActions"
                       sortOrder="200">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**\Vendor\ComputerGames\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ImageThumbnail**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\ComputerGames\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class ImageThumbnail extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $subDir = 'computer/image';

    public const ALT_FIELD = 'title';

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected StoreManagerInterface $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param Image $imageHelper
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface      $context,
        UiComponentFactory    $uiComponentFactory,
        Image        $imageHelper,
        UrlInterface          $urlBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array                 $components = [],
        array                 $data = []
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource): array
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $url = '';
                if ($item[$fieldName] != '') {
                    $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                        UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                    ) . $this->subDir . "/" . $item[$fieldName];
                }
                $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $url;
                $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) ?: '';
                $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                    'games/game/edit',
                    ['game_id' => $item['game_id']]
                );
                $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $url;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function getAlt($row)
    {
        $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
        return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
    }
}
```

**\Vendor\ComputerGames\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\GameActions**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\ComputerGames\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Grid\Renderer\Action\UrlBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class GameActions extends Column
{
    /**
     * Url paths
     */
    const GAME_URL_PATH_EDIT = 'games/game/edit';
    const GAME_URL_PATH_DELETE = 'games/game/delete';
    /**
     * @var UrlBuilder
     */

    protected UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected UrlInterface $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private string $editUrl;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     * @param string $editUrl
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        $editUrl = self::GAME_URL_PATH_EDIT
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->actionUrlBuilder = $actionUrlBuilder;
        $this->editUrl = $editUrl;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource): array
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['game_id'])) {
                    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        $this->editUrl,
                        ['game_id' => $item['game_id']]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('Edit')
                ];
                    $item[$name]['delete'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            self::GAME_URL_PATH_DELETE,
                            ['game_id' => $item['game_id']]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                        'title' => __('Delete ${ $.$data.name }'),
                        'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a ${
                        $.$data.name } record?')
                ]
            ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `forms.xml` where `path="vendor_module/index/upload"` instead `"vendor_module"` we have to past our `"admin_rote"`

Answer (score 0):

**\Vendor\ComputerGames\Controller\Adminhtml\Game\Edit**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\ComputerGames\Controller\Adminhtml\Game;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

/**
 * Edit the page
 *
 * Class Edit
 */
class Edit extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected PageFactory $resultPageFactory;
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected Registry $coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        Action\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Edit the record through regisstry
     *
     * @return ResultInterface|Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Edit Game'));
        $gameId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('game_id');
        $this->coreRegistry->register('game_id', $gameId);
        return $resultPage;
    }
    /**
     * _isAllowed
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Moazzam_ComputerGames::grid');
    }
}
```

**Vendor/ComputerGames/view/adminhtml/web/template/image-preview.html**

**image preview fix during update the image**

```
<div class="file-uploader-summary">
    <div class="file-uploader-preview">
        <a attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
            <img
                alt="Thumbnail Image"
                class="preview-image"
                tabindex="0"
                event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
                attr="
                    src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                    alt: $file.name">
        </a>
        <div class="actions">
            <button
                type="button"
                class="action-remove"
                data-role="delete-button"
                attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
                click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
                <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
    <div class="file-uploader-meta">
        <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>
    </div>
</div>
```